# Loop within a Loop when condition satisfies should return newsingleArray

Tags: reactjs, loops, foreach

I have two loops, when the condition is satisfied I want to return single array.
My configuration array is as follows

```
"configuration": [
            {
               "position": "O",
                "side": "L",
                "type": 21,
                "wheel": 1,
                "wheels": 20
            },
            {
                "position": "I",
                "side": "L",
                "type": 21,
                "wheel": 2,
                "wheels": 20
            },
]
```

My sensor array is as follows

```
“Sensor”: [
            {
                "pressure": 8126,
                "sub_item": "1",
                "temp": 16,
                "time": 1572243074,
            },
            {
                "pressure": 8205,
                "sub_item": "10",
                "temp": 18.3,
                "time": 1572243092,
            },
]
```

I am looping through sensor array from configuration array and making a condition here

```
let finalarray = []
configuration.forEach((e1) => sensorData.forEach((e2) => {
  if (e1.wheel == e2.sub_item) {
    finalarray.push(e1)
    finalarray.push(e2)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(finalarray))
  }
}
))
```

I am expecting final array should be single array with both configuration and sensor array but I am receiving two different arrays.

Comment: can you share your expected output sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you wish to merge your object values instead of pushing them separately in the array for which you can use the spread operator syntax

```js
const configuration = [
            {
               "position": "O",
                "side": "L",
                "type": 21,
                "wheel": 1,
                "wheels": 20
            },
            {
                "position": "I",
                "side": "L",
                "type": 21,
                "wheel": 2,
                "wheels": 20
            },
    ] 
    const sensorData = [
            {
                "pressure": 8126,
                "sub_item": "1",
                "temp": 16,
                "time": 1572243074,
            },
            {
                "pressure": 8205,
                "sub_item": "10",
                "temp": 18.3,
                "time": 1572243092,
            },
    ]
    let finalarray = []
    configuration.forEach((e1) => sensorData.forEach((e2) => {
      if (e1.wheel == e2.sub_item) {
        finalarray.push({...e1, ...e2})
      }
    }))
    console.log(finalarray)
```

Comment: Yes,this is what I was expecting.Thanks!